# UiPath Bot -Can we do automation testing of Uipath bots?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, uipath

I want to do the automation testing of UiPath attended and unattended bot. I am not able to identify the window dialog box getting generated from Uipath. Please advice me the tool which can identify objects and automate the UiPath bots.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you already try Orchestrator as the UiPath tool for automation testing?

Comment: Yes we want to invoke the bot through command prompt and want to test whether bot is functioning properly through automation tool.we were unable to identify the attended bots window dialogs through UFT .is there is any way we can do the automation testing of uipath bots

Comment: Sure you can do all this with Orchestrator. You should have a look on the UiPath Acedemy tutorials. They show you all you need.

Answer (score 3):

With uipath 20.4 community preview release there are new exciting features to create test cases in the UiPath studio itself. refer this link here.
https://forum.uipath.com/t/testing-capabilities-in-community-orchestrator-20-4-community-preview-release/210487

however I would imagine you will be on older versions of studio, which requires you to apply other approaches. here is few ways to automate the testing for UIPath processes.

- Using the Orchestrator APIs we can monitor the jobs in various ways

https://platform.uipath.com/kinooqmollho/kinoorgDefault/swagger/ui/index#/

1. Jobs APIs to get status of the jobs
2. Alerts API to get any alerts generated by the Job
3. RobotLogs api to get check specific logs you expect or not expect in
   the jobs

Apart from this, you could build a test automation script to verify
   the results of bot, directly on the applications to make sure results
   you expect are showing up there.

Answer (score 2):

Newevest versions of UiPath Studio already have testing built-in (`Test Activity`).
For full-fledged Automated Testing capabilities watch for the announcements early this year

Answer (score 1):

The newest versions of UiPath Studio already have testing built-in (Test Activity).

You can also take the tutorial in https://academy.uipath.com on how the test automation works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For running the BOT from command line you can use below syntac on CMD:

```
 "drive:\Users\username\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-20.10.4\UiRobot.exe" -file "..\path_of\Main.xaml"
```

For testing, if the BOT is running or not you could send an email every few minutes so that you can remotely get the heartbeat of the BOT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Uipath built in test activities or else if you want to find out which dialog box is creating hindrance you can always save screenshots of the exception and log all the activities properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).